CORS error in Socket connection over expres app
I have established a socket connection on my express server to the client side, which is working on React. It was working perfectly when both my servers were running locally. I have hosted my backend on AWS EC2  and my React app is still on localhost. Now the client side is throwing a CORS error while establishing the connection as follows

Access to XMLHttpRequest at
'https://ahammed.online/socket.io/?classroomId=66d195b810a08c5bdc8775e7&userId=66d1958b10a08c5bdc8775e2&EIO=4&transport=polling&t=P7XXub6'
from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy:
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
resource.

My HTTP requests have no issues with the CORS policies, everything is working fine. What am I missing here?
My socket connection is in a separate file where I initially created the express server.
//socket.ts file
import { Server } from "socket.io";
import express from 'express';

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app)
const io = new Server(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: API_ORIGIN, //"http://localhost:5173"
        credentials:true,
        methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
    }
});
io.on('connection',(socket)=>{
   //all other socket functionalites
}
export { app, io, server } 

//index.ts file
import cors from "cors"
import { app,server } from "./application/socket/socket";

 app.use(cors({
    origin: API_ORIGIN,
    credentials:true
    }))
server.listen(PORT,()=>{
    console.log(`server active on port:${PORT}`)
}) 

//client side
const socket = io(BASE_URL, {//baseURl points to DNS were the backend resides
                query: {
                    classroomId,
                    userId: activeUser
                },
                withCredentials: true
            });

